# On sourcetree, how can I recover stashes after checkout on a different branch?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I had some stashed changes while I was working on a branch.

I wanted to work locally on a different branch so I did checkout into a new branch and lost all the stashes from sourcetree sidebar.

Here is a screenshot of sourcetree:

[image: sourcetree]

If I type `git stash list` on my terminal I get a list of the stashes...

```
stash@{0}: On feature/SITE-5-doctor-name-at-checkin-success: Before commits
stash@{1}: WIP on feature/SITE-5-doctor-name-at-checkin-success: df48232 WIP show dummyDoctor on success page
stash@{2}: WIP on feature/SITE-5-doctor-name-at-checkin-success: 82b1aed Linting
stash@{3}: On feature/SITE-5-doctor-name-at-checkin-success: DEBUG
```

...so I know they are not lost.

How do I get them back to my sourcetree sidebar so I can use them in any of those branches?

Comment: Nevermind. I accidentally created a new workspace and was working there, so obviously the stashes were on the previous one. Switched wires but it's all good now.

Comment: to the down voter: how's a noob to learn the ways of SO without a comment?

Comment: In my case, the Stashes were scrolled out of view, in the LHS explorer, beneath Branches .. Tags .. Remotes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Stashes are indeed listed in the sidebar, but in your image they're collapsed. The 'Show' links next to Tags, Remotes, Stashes, etc only show on hover.

Note that trying to apply a stash from one branch to another branch may result in conflicts to resolve.  In this case, sourcetree will not delete your stash automatically, as it would usually, rather you'll need to right click and 'delete' stashes once you've successfully applied them.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) I am almost sure they weren't collapsed, but I was using two different windows pointing to the same repository in different branches. Unnecessarily confusing stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Click the arrow ,  clicking the word "Stashes" wont open the drop down

Comment: Note all: I have been using Fork and it is a better Git GUI. Sourcetree always had issues with merge conflicts. https://git-fork.com/